# Persist text input via Angular NgXS

Tags: angular, observable, ngxs

I have a component which I can navigate away from but I want the text `input` fields to maintain their values between these navigation changes.

The `input` looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" required [ngModel]="country" name="country" (ngModelChange)="autoChange('country',$event)" />
```

The relevant part of the component is this:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(FavouritesState.getCountry) country$: Observable<string>;

  country: string = '';

  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.country$.subscribe(c => {
      this.country = c;
    });
  }

  autoChange(field: string, $event: string): void {
    switch (field) { 
      case 'country': { 
        this.country = $event;
        this.store.dispatch(new Search.Country(this.country));
        break; 
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to one-way bind the value passed into the `input` to class variable `country` and dispatch changes to the typed text with `this.store.dispatch()`.

The state class looks like this:

```
@State<FavouritesStateModel>({
  name: 'favouritesState',
  defaults: {
    country: ''
  }
})

@Injectable()
export class FavouritesState {
  @Action(Search.Country)
  Country(ctx: StateContext<FavouritesStateModel>, action: string) {
    ctx.setState(patch({
      country: action
    }))
  }

  @Selector()
  static getCountry(state: FavouritesStateModel) {
    return state.country
  }
}
```

And the action class looks like this:

```
export namespace Search {
  export class Country {
    static readonly type = '[Search] Set Country';
    constructor(public country: string) {}
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this fairly basic (I thought) pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Implement text input persistence...

Input control:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" required [ngModel]="(country$ | async)" name="country" (ngModelChange)="autoChange('country',$event)" />
```

State class:

```
@State<FavouritesStateModel>({
  name: 'favouritesState',
  defaults: {
    country: ''
  }
})

@Injectable()
export class FavouritesState {
  @Action(Search.Country)
  Country(ctx: StateContext<FavouritesStateModel>, { country }: Search.Country) {
    ctx.setState(patch({
      country: country
    }))
  }

  @Selector()
  static getCountry(state: FavouritesStateModel) {
    return state.country
  }
}
```

And the action class:

```
export namespace Search {
  export class Country {
    static readonly type = '[Search] Set Country';
    constructor(public country: string) {}
  }
}
```